# How to share data between Two CardView in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application in which I have Two `Fragment` named as DealApp and DealStories,DealApp  have `CardView` and DealStories have also `CardView`.I want to send data from DealApp and receive Data in DealStories and set Data into DealStories `CardView`.

Comment: These two fragments relates to same activity ??

Comment: no,These are different Fragment

Comment: I think communication between fragments should be done via activity. And communication between fragment and activity can be done this way http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity.

Comment: My click event works fine but how to receive data from on fragment and set these data in another fragment containing cardview

Comment: Both  the fragments are initiated on the same activity? If so, then use the Activity as a kind of "middleware" to pass infromation from one fragment to another. If both of them are on different activities, then pass information from one activity to another and then update fragment with the new data from the holding activity.